# iOS 11 UISearchBar won't accept tintColor

Tags: uisearchbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

I've tried to implement the new search bar in iOS 11 into my app but for some reason I cannot get the search bar color to change with the navigation bar. Before the switch to the new style I changed the color with `UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = .DRGreen` in my AppDelagate but now it remains the default white color even with that change.
[Screen Shot of incorrect search bar color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VlxS.png) (sorry screenshot is a link, I do not have enough reputation to embed pictures yet.)

My Code:

```
import UIKit

class DirectoryTC: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

var teachers = [

    Redacted information


]
var filteredTeachers = [Teacher]()

var selectedTeacher = Teacher(name: "", email: "", roomNumber: "", website: "")

var searchController: UISearchController!
var resultsController = UITableViewController()

var searchText = ""

override func viewDidLoad()
{

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self

    if #available(iOS 11, *)
    {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.text = searchText

        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.DRGreen
        searchController.isActive = true
    }else
    {
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.DRGreen.cgColor

        present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    definesPresentationContext = true

    //Make Search Background Green
    //tableView.backgroundView = UIView()
    //tableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = .DRGreen

    //Remove Navigation Bar Border
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()


    //Add in the DR LOGO on top Bar
    addNavBarImage()

}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredTeachers = self.teachers.filter{ (teacher:Teacher) -> Bool in

        if teacher.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        {
            return true
        }else
        {
            return false
        }
    }

    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    if tableView == self.tableView
    {
        return self.teachers.count
    }else
    {
        return self.filteredTeachers.count
    }

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    let teacher : Teacher

    if tableView == self.tableView
    {
        teacher = teachers[indexPath.row]
    }else
    {
        teacher = filteredTeachers[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = teacher.name

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let teacher : Teacher

    if tableView == self.tableView
    {
        teacher = teachers[indexPath.row]
        selectedTeacher = teacher
    }else
    {
        teacher = filteredTeachers[indexPath.row]
        selectedTeacher = teacher
    }


    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "teacherDetail", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as? DirectoryDetailVC

    vc?.name = selectedTeacher.name
    vc?.email = selectedTeacher.email
    vc?.roomNumber = selectedTeacher.roomNumber
    vc?.website = selectedTeacher.website
}

func addNavBarImage() {

    let navBarController = navigationController!

    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DRNavigationBarLogo")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)

    let bannerWidth = navBarController.navigationBar.frame.size.width
    let bannerHeight = navBarController.navigationBar.frame.size.height

    let  bannerX = bannerWidth / 2 - image.size.width / 2
    let bannerY = bannerHeight / 2 - image.size.height / 2

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: bannerX, y: bannerY, width: bannerWidth, height: bannerHeight)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    navigationItem.titleView = imageView

}

}
```

Comment: having this issue too.... ios11 is kicking me in the butt right now

Comment: @hhanesand have you been able to find anything on this? I'm still stuck

Comment: no, nothing I do changes anything, setting colors manually gets reset at certain points. I'm shipping with color bugs, nothing more I can do without spending too much time on it

Answer (score 0):

You can change UISearchBar background color using like this method:

```
func setBackground(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    for subView in searchBar.subviews {
        for view in subView.subviews {
            if view.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UISearchBarBackground")!) {
                guard let imageView = view as? UIImageView else {
                    print("cast exception ui image view")
                    continue
                }
                imageView.image = nil
                imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.DRGreen
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and call this method after initialize the UISearchControl. 
For example:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    setBackground(searchBar: self.searchController.searchBar)
}
```

Comment: I tried to add that to my code but when I run it I get the following error 'Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)' where I call 'setBackground(searchBar: self.searchController.searchBar)'

Comment: Probably you call before initialize the UISearchController. You must call after than. For example inside of viewDidLayoutSubviews() can be a good place

Comment: Where is viewDidLayoutSubviews() ?

Comment: It is still not working. I put both the setBackground function and the viewDidLayoutSubviews function after the viewDid load function, and called the viewDidLayoutSubviews at the bottom of the viewDidLoad function, and I am still getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION at the line where I call setBackground in the viewDidLayoutSubViews function

Comment: You have defined searchController 2 times. One of them defined as global variable, other local variable. Remove the "let" in front of the local variable. Just use global variable and initialize once

Comment: Ah okay, I have resolved that and it is running without any errors but it is still  displaying as the default white search bar

Comment: Ok. How about storyboard? You do not need a UISearchBar there. if there is it you can remove. Because UISearchController has own search bar that you passed as a parameter.

Comment: No UISearchBar in storyboard. It's all done programmatically, the tableViewController is embedded in a navigation controller if that makes a difference